# How to shorten the Long Parameter List in a Clean and Proper Way

Tags: c#, winforms

So here's my code

```
public static class ButtonProperties
{
    public static void _ButtonProperties(Button btn_dashboard, Button btn_products, Button btn_supplier, Button btn_customer, Button btn_sales, Button btn_inventory, Button btn_settings)
    {
        btn_dashboard.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        btn_dashboard.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
        btn_products.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        btn_products.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
        btn_supplier.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        btn_supplier.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
        btn_customer.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        btn_customer.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
        btn_sales.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        btn_sales.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
        btn_inventory.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        btn_inventory.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
        btn_settings.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        btn_settings.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
    }
}
```

As you can see, this takes too many parameters and I'd like to make it shorter.

[image: Many parameters]

Comment: Just use a List<button> ?

Comment: You dont want to make everything `static`, that's not why you use an OP-language like `C#`. On this way yur whole application can only have a single `ButtonProperties`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I note that thank you, I'm using static here so i don't need to create new instance

Comment: @Anonymous Stack Overflow is not a forum. We don't modify titles to say that a question has been answered. A question is answered if you checked one as the answer (which you already did)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Ah, Noted that sir Thank you for correcting me :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it with [`params`-array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params):

```
public static class ButtonProperties
{
    public static void _ButtonProperties(params Button[] buttons)
    {
        foreach (Button b in buttons)
        {
            b.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            b.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can pass a single button, multiple(comma separated) or even a `Button[]`.

As an example:

```
ButtonProperties._ButtonProperties(btn_dashboard, btn_products);
```

Comment: you should show how this is called, as this is what makes this a better answer than the others.

Comment: This is pretty neat because it doesn't need a List

Comment: I would also advise the OP to call this method `SetFlatProperties()` rather than `_ButtonProperties()`

Comment: @PhilipSmith: You are right. I only wanted to post it ASAP, and the fix *(update the links, etc.)* but it seems I was beaten to this.

Comment: Glad to take your answer. Thank you

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I know, the naming is wrong, but this way there is no need to change anything in the original code, therefore I did not change the name.

Comment: @Julo It's common to fix as much as possible (and relevant) in answers here. Showing how to properly write code is pretty relevant.

Comment: Should i name in it as Dashboard instead something like that ?

Comment: @Anonymous, Dashboard  seems unrelated. If the function set a button properties to flat with no border. the name should be related to that. I will go for "SetButtonPropertiesFlat" or "SetButtonFlat". So just by reading the name I have a complet understanding of the function.

Comment: @Julo , you forgot how to call it, Anyone How can i call his answer ?
      ButtonProperties._ButtonProperties(whatsinhere);

Answer (score 3):

Instead of having a fixed brunch of param, You can have a List.

```
public static void SetButtonProperties(List<Button> buttons){
    foreach(var button in buttons){
        button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        button.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
    }
}
```

Calling it like :

```
 SetButtonProperties(new List<Button>{ btn_dashboard, btn_products, btn_supplier, ... })
```

Comment: Imo not really, I wish I had more information about those button and what make them eligible to this reset. Or to have a better name for "ButtonProperties"

Answer (score 3):

seeing as you're doing the same thing to each button, why not just pass a list?

```
public static void _ButtonProperties(List<Button> buttons)
{
    foreach (var button in buttons)
    {
         button.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
         button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
    }
}
```