# How to shorten a code for Binding Database to Datagridview in a Clean and Proper way

Tags: c#, winforms

I always wanted my code to be cleaner and readable. I'm here in order to achieve that. Since i'm a beginner, it's better to learn this early. I hope someone would be able to give me a suggestions and a proper way of doing these.

PS: I have Tabcontrol with 3 tabpage, 3 Datagridview and 3 Table in Database

HERE'S my Code

```
public partial class SIMSSupplier : UserControl
{
    ADDSupplier supply;
    public SIMSSupplier()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    public DataTable dbdataset;
    public DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    public string ID = "SPPLR-000";
    public int DeliveryID;
    public int OrderID;
    DataView db;
    public void SupplierDetails()
    {
        using (var con = SQLConnection.GetConnection())
        {
            using (var select = new SqlCommand("Select SupplierID, Companyname, Contactname, Contactnumber as 'Contact Number', Date, Address, Remarks from Supplier_Details", con))
            {
                using (var sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    sda.SelectCommand = select;
                    dbdataset = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dbdataset);
                    var bsource = new BindingSource();
                    bsource.DataSource = dbdataset;
                    Supplierview.DataSource = bsource;
                    sda.Update(dbdataset);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void DeliveryDetails()
    {
        using (var con = SQLConnection.GetConnection())
        {
            using (var select = new SqlCommand("Select PurchaseID, Supplier, Itemdescription, Date, Quantity, Unitcost, Amount, Salesinvoice, Codeitems, Patientname from Purchase_Delivery", con))
            {
                using (var sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    sda.SelectCommand = select;
                    dbdataset = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dbdataset);
                    var bsource = new BindingSource();
                    bsource.DataSource = dbdataset;
                    PurchaseDeliveries.DataSource = bsource;
                    sda.Update(dbdataset);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void OrderDetails()
    {
        using (var con = SQLConnection.GetConnection())
        {
            using (var select = new SqlCommand("Select PurchaseID, Supplier, Itemdescription, Date, Quantity, Unitcost, Amount, Salesinvoice, Codeitems, Patientname from Purchase_Order", con))
            {
                using (var sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    sda.SelectCommand = select;
                    dbdataset = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dbdataset);
                    var bsource = new BindingSource();
                    bsource.DataSource = dbdataset;
                    PurchaseOrder.DataSource = bsource;
                    sda.Update(dbdataset);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this question belongs to [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: As a tip, you know you can stack `using` blocks in C# right?

Comment: Working code should go to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hmmm, I ask these kind of questions 2 days ago, but no one said that to me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52385749/how-to-shorten-the-long-parameter-list-in-a-clean-and-proper-way

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into writing code that is DRY.  You're repeating the same code for each update.  You could have a single routine that updates a DataGrid:

```
private void UpdateDataGrid(DataGridView grid, string sql)
{
    using (var connection = SQLConnection.GetConnection())
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
    {
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        dbdataset = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dbdataset);
        grid.DataSource = new BindingSource { DataSource = dbdataset };
        adapter.Update(dbdataset);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is these code is working for 3 Tables ? There are difference in select query because they are selecting different tables

Comment: @Anonymous you pass in the select query via the `sql` parameter.

Comment: Thank you for helping , I will be glad to take it

Comment: Also note in your posted code, you might be updating the wrong grid in `OrderDetails`.

Answer (score 0):

If I was you AND if you don't want to change your code architecture, i would refactor the similar code if all your futur request are gonna to have the same code.

```
public partial class SIMSSupplier : UserControl
{
    private ADDSupplier supply;
    public DataTable dbdataset;
    public DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    public string ID = "SPPLR-000";
    public int id;
    DataView db;

    public SIMSSupplier()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public void SupplierDetails()
    {
        DoRequestAndFill(Supplierview, "Select SupplierID, Companyname, Contactname, Contactnumber as 'Contact Number', Date, Address, Remarks from Supplier_Details");
    }
    public void DeliveryDetails()
    {
        DoRequestAndFill(PurchaseDeliveries, "Select PurchaseID, Supplier, Itemdescription, Date, Quantity, Unitcost, Amount, Salesinvoice, Codeitems, Patientname from Purchase_Delivery");
    }
    public void OrderDetails()
    {
        DoRequestAndFill(PurchaseOrders, "Select PurchaseID, Supplier, Itemdescription, Date, Quantity, Unitcost, Amount, Salesinvoice, Codeitems, Patientname from Purchase_Order");
    }

    private void DoRequestAndFill(DataGridView grid, string request) 
    {
        using (var con = SQLConnection.GetConnection())
        using (var select = new SqlCommand(request, con))
        using (var sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            dbdataset = new DataTable();
            sda.SelectCommand = select;
            sda.Fill(dbdataset);
            grid.DataSource = new BindingSource() { DataSource = dbdataset };
            sda.Update(dbdataset); 
        }
    }
}
```

It depent the size of your project and what do you want, but you should probably think about doing it in MVC architecture. At least all database's call to the should be in another class.

Also, i don't really like same name like

```
    public string ID = "SPPLR-000";
    public int id;
```

As first read i should know what is it, and this is little bit confusing. If you stop your program and back to it after few months, you will probably be confused too (i don't see where is used in your code).

Finally, consider using the keyword "const" if your "ID" is a parameter and if the value is not gonna to change.

Hope i was helpfull

Comment: You need to have a `DataGridView` passed into `DoRequestAndFill`, because he's updating different grids.  See my basically identical answer.

Comment: Thank you for helping , I will be glad to take your suggestions. There's so many different design patterns out there, MVC is good, but i'm not aiming for that :)

Comment: Well, without doing pure mvc, you should put the model (database access) in separate class for many reason : If you want to change your DB a day, all your call will be at the same place. If you want to optmise or if you are looking for a specific call, all here too. You can use abstract class / static method for simple call (or implement the singleton patern)

Comment: Note that `OrderDetails` likely needs a grid named `PurchaseOrders` per OP's latest comments.

Comment: @BenjaminK I just want to clarify this sir  "Finally, consider using the keyword "const" if your "ID" is a parameter and if the value is not gonna to change" What do you mean by values is not gonna change ? my id is incrementing it's changing ?

Comment: Forget if your value is changing. But can you explain what "ID" and "id" are ? Is "id" the numeric value of the end of "ID" ?

Comment: When do you use your ID ? How do you increment it ?

Comment: You can reduce work by using the Entity Framework instead of SQL Client classes. This provides strongly typed classes of data. As said above, for MVC, your Controller should have as little code in as possible. Use Direct Injection to pass in an interface, in which all of the calls you require are defined. Then you have just one-liners to get your data that are agnostic to change. Having said that, I do sometimes use the above code for very small Windows-Forms  projects